# Is default navbar on Material UI exist like Bootstrap does?

Tags: reactjs, navbar, material-ui, react-bootstrap, appbar

I found it hard to create navbar with menus on Material UI. I've read it's AppBar documentation. But, it seems they doesn't provide that feature.

1) Material UI AppBar

[image]

2) React Bootstrap Navbar

[image]

How to create navbar menu on Material UI like React Bootstrap does ?

Comment: @HemersonCarlin .. no, what i want is the navbar of Material UI has menu

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Material-UI doesn't provide a `navbar` component like Bootstrap does. (It does have an [appbar](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar) though, but I don't think that's what you're looking for). Also, it doesn't give you the automatic responsiveness out-of-the-box like bootstrap. It just gives you the tools so you have to take care of it yourself.

[image]

A navbar, however can be composed using some basic MUI components with flex:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Box, Typography, Button, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box display="flex" bgcolor="grey.200" p={2} alignItems="center">
      <Typography>React-bootstrap</Typography>
      <Box>
        <Button color="primary">Link</Button>
        <Button color="primary">Link</Button>
      </Box>
      <Box flexGrow={1} textAlign="right">
        <IconButton>
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here's the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hoover-ldl3g?file=/src/App.js):

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the appbar (https://mui.com/components/app-bar/) component with something like the drawer component (https://mui.com/components/drawers/).

Apparently this 'atomic' approach is what MUI proposes to us (configure the building blocks and make your own components). I struggled a bit with grasping this component as well but I m starting to get the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

An AppBar is more or less just a container for other components. It doesn't do much on its own. What I think you want is to add a menu to you AppBar (or, more specifically, to the Toolbar inside of the AppBar):

https://material-ui.com/components/menus/

You can also add regular Buttons:

https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

A simplified example:

```
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Menu>
            <MenuItem>An item</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Another item</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
          <Button>A button</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```